# Grails Databinding of Embedded Boolean

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I have a problem with automatic data binding of boolean which is in embedded class. I created an example for this:

Domain Class:

```
class TestMe {

   TestEmbedded testEmbedded = new TestEmbedded()

   static embedded = ['testEmbedded']

   static constraints = {
   }
}
```

Embedded Class:

```
class TestEmbedded {

   String stringEmbedded = "test"
   Boolean booleanEmbedded = false
}
```

Controller:

```
class TestMeController {

    static scaffold = true
}
```

Scaffolded edit and creat renders inputs properly. When I create or edit an instant, embedded properties work fine. There is only one issue. When I try to edit a TestMe.testEmbedded.booleanEmbedded from true value to false value (using checkbox) (other way round edit works!), the data binding doesn't work. Is it a bug of grails? Is there any good workround?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the field is actually being passed when set to false by printing the params in the controller.  You'll have to create a dummy update method in the controller to test this:

```
class TestController {

    static scaffold = true

    def update() {
        params.each {
            printing it
        }
    }
}
```

Standard HTML forms don't send unchecked checkboxes; Grails creates a hidden variable (which is always sent) with an underscore in front of the checkbox name to handle this if you are using `g:checkBox`

If the form isn't using the `g:checkBox` you can either create the hidden variable manually or handle it with logic in the controller.  Viewing the source of the generated page could be helpful.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: I'm using the g:checkBox for the checkboxes, therefore it uses the underscore property. The problem is exactly that the Grails data-binding works when it's a property of domain class but not when it's a property of embedded class. And to be honest I don't want to change the controller I would like to leave the scaffolding there. Any solution?:-)

Answer (score 0):

I've created a Grails Issue for this because it seems to be a bug of Grails.

http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9664

Comment: Same problem here, really annoying. What would be a workaround?